Z-Clipping / Depth-Clipping in a Javascript 3D Engine
I have created a Javascript 3D model viewer where you can load a wavefront .obj model using a python program that I used and display it in your web browser.
I have a problem with z-clipping where if the camera gets too close to a polygon it disappears due to the no vertices/polygons behind the camera rule, how can I clip it?
Here is a very crude build of the project, ported to replit: replit/js-3d-2
Here is some of the code that is in the project that has to be corrected in order for this to work (again, I have just began my web-dev programming):
function findIntercept(x1, y1, x2, y2, line) {
  return y1 + ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)) * (line - x1);
}

function clipMinusPolygon(polygon, line) {
  let clippedPolygon = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < polygon.length; i += 2) {
    let x1 = polygon[i];
    let y1 = polygon[i + 1];
    let x2 = polygon[(i + 2) % polygon.length];
    let y2 = polygon[(i + 3) % polygon.length];

    if (x1 > line && x2 > line) {
      clippedPolygon.push(x1, y1);
    } else if (x1 <= line && x2 <= line) {
      // Skip the entire edge
    } else {
      let interceptY = findIntercept(x1, y1, x2, y2, line);
      if (x1 > line) {
        clippedPolygon.push(x1, y1);
        clippedPolygon.push(line, interceptY);
      } else {
        clippedPolygon.push(line, interceptY);
        clippedPolygon.push(x2, y2);
      }
    }
  }
  return clippedPolygon;
}

function clipPositivePolygon(polygon, line) {
  let clippedPolygon = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < polygon.length; i += 2) {
    let x1 = polygon[i];
    let y1 = polygon[i + 1];
    let x2 = polygon[(i + 2) % polygon.length];
    let y2 = polygon[(i + 3) % polygon.length];

    if (x1 < line && x2 < line) {
      clippedPolygon.push(x1, y1);
    } else if (x1 >= line && x2 >= line) {
      // Skip the entire edge
    } else {
      let interceptY = findIntercept(x1, y1, x2, y2, line);
      if (x1 < line) {
        clippedPolygon.push(x1, y1);
        clippedPolygon.push(line, interceptY);
      } else {
        clippedPolygon.push(line, interceptY);
        clippedPolygon.push(x2, y2);
      }
    }
  }
  return clippedPolygon;
}

function sortAndDraw() {
  polygonDistance.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b;});
  polygonDistance.reverse();

  for (let i = 0; i < polygonDistance.length; i++) {
    const key = polygonDistance[i];
    let polygon = 0;

    for (polygon = 0; polygon < polygonDistance.length; polygon++) {
      if (allCoordinates[polygon][0] === key) {
        break;
      }
    }

    if (polygon < polygonDistance.length) {
      ctx.beginPath();

      let clippedPolygon = clipMinusPolygon(allCoordinates[polygon].slice(1,allCoordinates[polygon].length-1), 10);

      clippedPolygon = clipPositivePolygon(clippedPolygon, canvas.width-10);

      for (let j = 0; j < clippedPolygon.length; j += 2) {
        ctx.lineTo(clippedPolygon[j], clippedPolygon[j+1]);
      }
      ctx.fillStyle = changeColor(allCoordinates[polygon][allCoordinates[polygon].length - 1], polygonDistance[i]/3);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      ctx.strokeStyle = changeColor(allCoordinates[polygon][allCoordinates[polygon].length - 1], polygonDistance[i]/3);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }

}

If you know, please assist me! Thanks, xela.
Failed attempts:

I tried to do the same clipping that I did to the x axis but replace them with z
Following youtube/3d-graphics-javidx9, its helpfull but it's C++ so it doesn't exactly fit my needs.
I tried following some wikipedia articles and websites.

